# How to draw large sized text on a canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas, drawtext

I want to draw on canvas month's text vertical along screen height.

Paint init:

```java
   this.paint = new Paint();
   this.paint.setAntiAlias(true);
   this.paint.setDither(true);
   this.paint.setSubpixelText(true);
   this.paint.setColor(color_text_dark);
   this.paint.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);
```

Drawing:

```java
   // Set the scale to the widest month
   float scale = getHeight() / this.max_month_width;
   String month_string = FULL_MONTH_NAME_FORMATTER.
                         format(active_month_calendar.getTime());
   canvas.save();
   canvas.translate(getWidth(), 0);
   canvas.rotate(-90);
   canvas.scale(scale, scale);
   canvas.drawText(month_string, 0, 0, this.paint);
   canvas.restore();
```

<s>Result looks good on *hdpi* screen, but very ugly and pixelated on *xhdpi* one.</s>

I did more test on various devices, and understood what result depends on Android version, not screen density and resolution.

Code works fine on 2.x platform, but doesn't work on 4.0.3+. Suppose, Android draw implementation was changed here.
Full code you can see [here](https://github.com/openintents/openintents/blob/master/calendarpicker/CalendarPicker/src/org/openintents/calendarpicker/view/FlingableMonthView.java).

<s>**hdpi**</s> version **2.3.5** (also tested **2.2**)

[image: hdpi]

<s>**xhdpi**</s> version **4.2** (also tested **4.1**, **4.0.3**)

[image: xhdpi]

Trying different variations for paint antialias, subpixel text has no effect. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you're drawing text at one size and scaling the result up. Once you've determined how wide you want the text to be, you should use calls to Paint.measureText(), adjusting the size via Paint.setTextSize() accordingly. Once it measures correctly, then you do your call to Canvas.drawText().

An alternative would be to not measure the text at all and just immediately call:

```
paint.setTextSize(paint.getSize() * scale)
```

There's no guarantee the text will fit in this case, though.

None of your other transform calls should result in interpolation, so it should give you very sharp lines.

*Edit*

Here is a code sample and comparison screenshot:

```
canvas.save();
canvas.scale(10, 10);
canvas.drawText("Hello", 0, 10, mTextPaint);
canvas.restore();
float textSize = mTextPaint.getTextSize();
mTextPaint.setTextSize(textSize * 10);
canvas.drawText("Hello", 0, 300, mTextPaint);
mTextPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
```

[image: Your rendering method on top, mine on bottom]

Comment: hmm, thanks, but that code already works on some devices. See my updated post above.

Comment: Updated the answer. The rendering method changed (in Honeycomb, maybe?) so that the text is written to a buffer and then scaled up. The only way you'll get rid of the interpolation is by setting the text size larger *before* drawing it to the canvas.

Comment: You're right. Found discussion about this: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/TH7ulKMbcpc/discussion

Comment: I found the same problem with pathes ( drawpath ). How can we solve this problem with pathes ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have enough reputation to comment on Krylez's excellent answer, but I'd like to reply to mcfly soft's comment/question about paths.

The idea is the same for paths as text. Instead of scaling and translating the canvas a path is drawn on, put the same scaling and translation into a matrix and pass that to Path.transform:

```
// instead of this:
canvas.scale(sX, sY);
canvas.translate(trX, trY);
canvas.drawPath(path);

// do this:
matrix.postScale(sX, sY);
matrix.postTranslate(trX, trY);
path.transform(matrix);
canvas.drawPath(path);
```