# What's the difference between Path.transform and Canvas.scale

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap, path, android-canvas

I wish to scale a path that would be drew to the `Canvas`. I am wondering what's the difference between the following two options:

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.scale(factor, factor);
    canvas.draw(path, paint);
}
```

and

```
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    // prepare the matrix here
    ....
    path.transform(matrix);
    canvas.draw(path, paint);
}
```

My understanding is that: the first one will transform the `Canvas` itself rather than the object to be drew, like a path; the second one is to transform the object itself.

What's the difference here? Which option should I use in what kind of situations? What's happening under the hood in terms of the underlying `Bitmap` of the `Canvas`? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume this in regards to making a path bigger.

Using `Canvas.Scale()` you make the canvas smaller, draw to it, then make it bigger again ( i think you are missing a step).

Where as `Path.transform` Makes the path bigger, then draws this to the canvas.

The scaling method, is going to pixelate the path, as it is being resized after drawing.
Where as transform will resize it better, as it is resizing the vector path before drawing.

If you are making the path Smaller.. there will be no visible effect worth noting. Except maybe the line widths.

Comment: Assuming I intend to make the path bigger; how could canvas.scale() make the canvas smaller as you mentioned? The doc says: "Preconcat the current matrix with the specified scale".

Comment: @wizoleliam See the example of it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14543066/940834). As you can see, pixelation occurs. It may not be physically resizing it, but is drawing it as if a smaller size canvas, then scaling those results back causing pixelation. The rest of the image should be unaffected by such a scale.

Comment: thank you for the link. Yet I doubt the path is also pixelated as the case of text. I zoomed in at 5x, the path didn't get blurred at all, but got much thicker. Btw, if "drawing it as if a smaller size canvas" is true, the width/height or bounds of the canvas should be smaller, but the dimensions of the canvas remained the same.