# The app screen is smaller on my phone

Tags: android, canvas, view

I have made a snake app, that uses a canvas:

the  xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/screen"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/surface"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

    </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/gameover"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/gameover"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/scoretv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Would you like to save it?" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:hint="Enter name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/yes"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/no"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No Tnx, Back to menu" />

    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/stoped"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/gameover"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Do you you want to leave?" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="center" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/Continue"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Continue Game" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/leave"
                style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Leave to menu" />

    </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>



<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/down"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/down"
        android:src="@drawable/right" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/down"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/down"
        android:src="@drawable/left" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/up"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right"
        android:src="@drawable/up" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/down"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/up"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/down" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Go Back To Menu" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Pause"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Pause" />

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

the Activity:(part of it, with out all the clicklisteners)

```
public class ClassicActivity extends Activity  {
Classic g;

ImageView left;
ImageView right;
ImageView up;
ImageView down;

TextView pause;
TextView back;

TextView scoretv;

LinearLayout surface;

LinearLayout screen;

LinearLayout stoped;
LinearLayout gameover;

ScoreDataSource sds;

Button no;
Button yes;
EditText name;
Button continueb;
Button leave;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_classic);
    sds=new ScoreDataSource(this);
    gameover=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.gameover);
    screen = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.screen);
    surface = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.surface);
    g= new Classic(this, surface);
    surface.addView(g);
```

No i am not brining the Class `Classic` becaouse it a realy bigone that uses other classes also, so it just uses a canvas to draw on the view, i have set that the snake width and the walls will be 10(that might be the problem), but for the writing i havent set width, just the corrdinates and the color (`your score:x`).

here is  screen shot of the game on my phone and on the emulator:

on the emulator:

[image]

on my phone:[image]

if you need me to add more code, or data just say i am not sure what i was suppose to upload.

How can I make them match?Thanks for the help

Comment: You are using **pixels** when drawing... you should scale them to your current `screen density`. So to make them become **dp**.

Comment: Simply find the scale factor based on your current density. Then multiply all (coordinates, sizes, ...) by that factor. `final float scale = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;`

Comment: I made it an answer, for future users with the same issue.

Comment: the text: canvas.drawText() is still small, and it doesnt still fit the whole screen.I thought that it was because i had all the coordinates and other sizes in int but now i have transfared them to float and yet its still the same, not as small as it was at the begining but not as big as it should be

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14543066/2649012) to a similar post

Comment: I edited my answer. But now I have a question: why drawing your text? you could use TextViews for scores, lives, ... So these would be automatically scaled by Android (by having their sizes set in sp).

Comment: i am using a thread,i cant change them while i am in that thread and i  want to display the score of the player each time he earns points, not only at the end. Thanks!

Comment: It could be done... anyway, see my edited answer to get more hints. (normally text sizes are in sp, not in dp, so you could benefit from the update I made to my answer). I say you, but I mean us. One day I plan to make some game too. But I'll try the TextView way first. Then I'll eventually fall back to the draw text on canvas method.

Comment: My pleasure. Keep developing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using **pixels** when drawing... you should scale them to your current `screen density`.
So to make them become **dp**.

Simply find the **scale factor** based on your current `screen density`.
Then multiply all (coordinates, sizes, ...) by that factor:

```
final float scale = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

**[EDIT]**

Consider the difference between dp and sp (used for text).

The dp has constant scale transition to px: `dp = px * scale`

While sp has a scalable ratio: `sp = px * scale * ratio` or `sp = dp * ratio`
This ratio can be used by people who need larger font sizes, for example, to use a device more comfortably.

Let's say you want the text to be the 25% more than the dp scaling (which is really the 125%), the ratio will be 1.25.

Answer (score 0):

Change your LinearLayout to match_parent.

Comment: Test with Graphical Layout