# Using pinchable zoom ViewGroup RelativeLayout , reduces quality of textview android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, pinchzoom

I'm using a relative layout with pinching zoom gestures enabled (The code is provided below in *ZoomableViewGroup.java*). And when I pinch it the quality of the TextView within it reduces. The structure of the project is very simple it has a MainActivity with the layout of *main_activity.xml* which the code is provided below.

**main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.example.test.ZoomableViewGroup
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/activity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Hello"/>
</com.example.test.ZoomableViewGroup>
```

***ZoomableViewGroup.java***

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class ZoomableViewGroup extends RelativeLayout {


    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1;

    public ZoomableViewGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    public ZoomableViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    public ZoomableViewGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return true;
    }

    protected void dispatchDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.save(Canvas.MATRIX_SAVE_FLAG);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        super.dispatchDraw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();
            // Apply limits to the zoom scale factor:
            invalidate();
            requestLayout();
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of size are you using for textview? dp? sp?

Comment: I'm using sp for the size of the text.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5535672/3743245 you'll need an AutoScaleTextView for that or a custom font that handles the auto size

Comment: You can't scale canvas and text without font scaling. I suppose your problem looks like here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14541727/how-to-draw-large-sized-text-on-a-canvas