# Android: write on an image resource and keep the same size on different devices

Tags: android, canvas, paint, drawtext, text-size

I have been looking for days on how to fix my issue and haven't really found an answer. So I apologize in advance if there already is a similar question.

My problem is simple. I want the user to input a name, and this name will be written on an image, in some kind of little box. (The image is then shared in an intent and everything, anyway...)

The image is a png in my drawable folder. So it should always have the same size in pixels on any kind of device. 
I load the png on a bitmap, use canvas on that bitmap, create a paint and `myPaint.setTextSize(100)` (setTextSize takes pixels so in this case it is 100 pixels) and then drawText on the canvas using that paint to have the same text size (in pixel) from whatever device is used.

The result is that writing "MyName" on one device fits perfectly, but on a smaller device would go out of the box, and on a larger device also.

I tried to use dp or sp, even if I knew it wouldn't change anything because we aren't talking about a layout, but a drawable png that has a fixed size.'

I have no issue with the position of the text or anything; only the size of it.

So anyway, I don't know where this change of textsize from one device to another comes from. Maybe I am not taking care of some kind of detail. I hope you guys can help me out.

```
                    Context context = getBaseContext();
                    Resources resources = context.getResources();
                    Bitmap card = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.card);

                    android.graphics.Bitmap.Config bitmapConfig = card.getConfig();
                    if(bitmapConfig == null) {
                        bitmapConfig = android.graphics.Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
                    }
                    // Converting to mutable
                    card = card.copy(bitmapConfig, true);

                    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(card);
                    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
                    // text color
                    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                    paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
                    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
                    // text size in pixels
                    paint.setTextSize(100);

                    // Name Position
                    float xName = (float) (0.744 * card.getWidth() );
                    float yName = (float) (0.680424 * (card.getHeight() - (paint.ascent()/2)));
                    String name = editName.getText().toString();
                    canvas.drawText(name, xName, yName, paint);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14543066/2931489

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
/**
     * Sets the text size for a Paint object so a given string of text will be a
     * given width.
     * 
     * @param paint
     *            the Paint to set the text size for
     * @param desiredWidth
     *            the desired width
     * @param text
     *            the text that should be that width
     */
    private static void setTextSizeForWidth(Paint paint, float desiredWidth,
            String text) {

        // Pick a reasonably large value for the test. Larger values produce
        // more accurate results, but may cause problems with hardware
        // acceleration. But there are workarounds for that, too; refer to
        // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253528/font-size-too-large-to-fit-in-cache
        final float testTextSize = 48f;

        // Get the bounds of the text, using our testTextSize.
        paint.setTextSize(testTextSize);
        Rect bounds = new Rect();
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

        // Calculate the desired size as a proportion of our testTextSize.
        float desiredTextSize = testTextSize * desiredWidth / bounds.width();

        // Set the paint for that size.
        paint.setTextSize(desiredTextSize);
    }
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for answering. This code is useful to resize a text so that a longer name can still fit in a box, and could be an alternative solution. But what would be perfect is a solution to the fact that two exact same texts with the same length on different devices draw differently on the image.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by using density. Not really sure how it works, but it gets the job done so...

```
Resources resources = context.getResources();
float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
paint.setTextSize(30 * scale);
```